# Lowest pair sequential combination data table

Tags: r, data.table, combinations

I have a set with two columns. The rows are pairs of values (a,b).

```
require(data.table)        
dt<-data.table(a=c(1,11,11,2,7,5,6), b = c(2,9,8,6,5,3,3))
```

I want to assign to each pair of values the lowest number. **BUT if one of the values appears again in a new line, it must be compared again with the new pair and selected the lowest of the history**. The result must be this one:

```
res.dt<-data.table(a=c(1,11,11,2,7,5,6), b = c(2,9,8,6,5,3,3), res=c(1,9,8,1,5,3,1))        

    a b res
1:  1 2   1
2: 11 9   9
3: 11 8   8
4:  2 6   1
5:  7 5   5
6:  5 3   3
7:  6 3   1
```

Comment: Should the value of 'res' be 5 for the 5th element?

Comment: Looks like a network analysis problem to me. Not sore how to solve this efficiently. Is your data very big?

Comment: @akrun As you pointed, the 5th res had a mistake. I already corrected.

Comment: @DavidArenburg My data is very big

Comment: @Alfredo_MF How many rows?

Comment: @sirallen around 100,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To state the problem differently:  For each row *i*, we need to iteratively update `res` with the smallest value in rows *j* <= *i* where (a_i,b_i) and (a_j,b_j) have a non-empty intersection.

We can do this efficiently with [non-equi joins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-TtPqBYUMU) in `data.table` (v>=1.9.8), but since this feature only allows single-element comparisons (`>`,`>=`,`==`,`<=`, or `<`), we need to find intersections by comparing (a_i,a_j), (a_i,b_j), (b_i,a_j), (b_i,b_j) separately. (There is an intersection if at least one of these pairs contains identical elements.) Doing this iteratively accounts for the entire history, and we can stop when the result converges:

```
dt[, `:=`(idx=.I, res=pmin(a,b), prev_res=NA)]

while (dt[, !identical(res, prev_res)]) {
  dt[, prev_res:= res]

  # Use non-equi joins to update 'res' for intersecting pairs downstream
  dt[dt[, .(i.a=a, i.res=res, i=.I)], on=.(a==i.a, idx > i), res:= pmin(res, i.res)]

  dt[dt[, .(i.a=a, i.res=res, i=.I)], on=.(b==i.a, idx > i), res:= pmin(res, i.res)]

  dt[dt[, .(i.b=b, i.res=res, i=.I)], on=.(a==i.b, idx > i), res:= pmin(res, i.res)]

  dt[dt[, .(i.b=b, i.res=res, i=.I)], on=.(b==i.b, idx > i), res:= pmin(res, i.res)]

}
```

The result:

```
> dt[, .(a,b,res)]
#     a b res
# 1:  1 2   1
# 2: 11 9   9
# 3: 11 8   8
# 4:  2 6   1
# 5:  7 5   5
# 6:  5 3   3
# 7:  6 3   1
```